# Unable to extract html from template.js created using grunt-html2js

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, ng-html2js

I am using html2js with grunt in my application which is creating a template.js which comprises of all my html templates. I am using my app.js to get the templates for the files like this:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider.state('abcde', {
            url: '/',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/sections/section1/section1.tpl.html'
        })
```

What should I now declare for the template url to get the template from template.js?